# Multiplying a matrix with array of vectors in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication, shapes

I'm trying to geometrically rotate an array of vectors in NumPy. First I generate the coordinate vectors of a grid.

```
width = 128
height = 128

x_axis = np.linspace(-1, 1, width)
y_axis = np.linspace(-1, 1, height)

x, y = np.meshgrid(x_axis, y_axis)
z = np.full((width, height), 0)
vectors = np.stack((x, y, z), axis=2)
```

So 'vectors' has the shape (128, 128, 3)

I already prepared the rotation matrix with a, b and c as the rotation angles along the axes.

```
rotation_matrix = np.array([
    [np.cos(b) * np.cos(c),
     - np.cos(b) * np.sin(c),
     np.sin(b)],

    [np.sin(a) * np.sin(b) * np.cos(c) + np.cos(a) * np.sin(c),
     - np.sin(a) * np.sin(b) * np.sin(c) + np.cos(a) * np.cos(c),
     - np.sin(a) * np.cos(b)],

    [- np.cos(a) * np.sin(b) * np.cos(c) + np.sin(a) * np.sin(c),
     np.cos(a) * np.sin(b) * np.sin(c) + np.sin(a) * np.cos(c),
     np.cos(a) * np.cos(b)]
])
```

Now I want every vector of the array to be matrix multiplied with 'rotation_matrix' like

```
vector_rotated = rotation_matrix @ vector
```

so the resulting array also should have the shape (128, 128, 3). I have some problems with handling this 3 dimensional array. Matmul is only capable of handling 2d arrays. Is there any elegant way in NumPy for this use case or do I have to use a for loop to solve this issue?

Thanks a lot and have a nice day!

Comment: `matmul` handles 3d and larger, but the `dot` product is on the last 2 dimensions, while the first ones are 'batches'.  `np.einsum` is another tool for doing higher dimensional products.

Comment: A (128,128,3) works with a (3,3).  In `A@B` the last dimension of `A` pairs with the 2nd to the last of `B`, the standard matrix product (across columns down rows).

Comment: @hpaulj Just to be clear, `A@B`, where `A` is the vectors and `B` is the rotation matrix would "work", in that the dimensions would be consistent. But that's not the same thing as rotation, in which `A` would be _left-multiplied_ by `B`. Just making sure we're all on the same page here :)

Comment: @bnaecker, `vectors@rotation_matrix.T` matches your rotations.

Comment: @hpaulj Yep, definitely! I was just mapping your comment onto the arrays in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways to solve this problem.

#### Option 1:

The most straightforward is to reshape the array `vectors` so that it has shape `(3, 128 * 128)`, then call the builtin `np.dot` function, and reshape the result back to your desired shape.

(Note that the `(128, 128)` part of the array's shape is not really relevant to the rotation; it's an interpretation that you probably want to make your problem clearer, but makes no difference to the linear transformation you want to apply. Said another way, you are rotating 3-vectors. There are `128 * 128 == 16384` of them, they just happen to be organized into a 3D array like above.)

This approach would look like:

```py
>>> v = vectors.reshape(-1, 3).T
>>> np.dot(rotation_matrix, v).shape
(3, 16384)
>>> rotated = np.dot(rotation_matrix, v).T.reshape(vectors.shape)
>>> rotated.shape == vectors.shape
True
```

#### Option 2:

Another method that does not involve any reshaping is to use NumPy's [Einstein summation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html?highlight=einsum#numpy.einsum). Einstein summation is very flexible, and takes a while to understand, but its power justifies its complexity. In its simplest form, you "label" the axes that you want to multiply together. Axes that are omitted are "contracted", meaning a sum across that axis is computed. For your case, it would be:

```py
>>> np.einsum('ij,klj->kli', rotation_matrix, vectors).shape
(128, 128, 3)
>>> np.allclose(rotated, np.einsum('ij,klj->kli', rotation_matrix_vectors))
True
```

Here's a quick explanation of the indexing. We are labeling the axes of the rotation matrix `i` and `j`, and the axes of the vectors `k`, `l`, and `j`. The repeated `j` means those are the axes multiplied together. This is equivalent to right-multiplying the reshaped array above with the rotation matrix (i.e., it's a rotation).

The output axes are labeled `kli`. This means we're preserving the `k` and `l` axes of the vectors. Since `j` is not in the output labels, there is a summation across that axis. Instead we have the axis `i`, hence the final shape of `(128, 128, 3)`. You can see above that the dot-product method and the `einsum` method agree.

It can take a while to wrap your head around Einstein summation, but it is super awesome and powerful. I highly recommend learning more about it, especially if this sort of linear algebra is a common problem for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped me a lot! :)